# Regular expression Search - word in another word

Tags: regex

I have a search requirement. 
For example,  I am want to search a word "Microsoft Account" in a large content.
In the large text, it may be defined like 
"Microsoft_Account" or "Microsoft-Account". 
My search logic should identify the above words also. 
Is there any way to implement this using regular expression?
(can be done by splitting and loop search but would be great if any solution using regular expression)

Comment: `Foo[ -]Bar` matches `Foo Bar` and `Foo-Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the regEx, it's : `a[ -_]b`

Where `a` and `b` are the two part of what you search

---

If you need an algo :

You need to first split you search word (in many language this `yourString.split(regex)`) whit th regex spliter : `[ -_]` that will allow the three different caracter.

In many cas, `split` return a table of string. So then you have to look in your table to recreate your regex.

> Algorithm

```
str = your_search_string
tab_string = str.split("[ -_]")

res = ""
foreach part in tab_string
    res = res + part + "[ -_]"
endForeach
res = res[0 length-5] //to remove "[ -_]" at the end
```

with this little algorithm you will have for your exemple :

```
str = "Microsoft Account"
tab_string = ["Microsoft", "Account"]
res = ""

forEach
|   res = "Microsoft[ -_]"
|   res = "Microsoft[ -_]Account[ -_]"
EndforEach
res = "Microsoft[ -_]Account"
```